# Issue Creating Knowledge Base Document

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create an `EXTRACTIVE_QA` type knowledge base article using the sample code from the nodejs-dialogflow repository. However, when I try to create it with a specific MIME-type, it fails. What MIME-types are supported for `EXTRACTIVE_QA`?

I've tried both text/plain and text/html with no luck. Creating FAQ type documents doesn't run into the same issues and creating the document by uploading a HTML file from the Dialogflow console works fine.

```
async function createDocument(projectId, knowledgeBaseFullName, documentPath) {
  const dialogflow = require('dialogflow').v2beta1;

  // Instantiate a DialogFlow Documents client.
  const client = new dialogflow.DocumentsClient({
    projectId: projectId,
  });

  const request = {
    parent: knowledgeBaseFullName,
    document: {
      knowledgeTypes: ['EXTRACTIVE_QA'],
      displayName: 'test',
      contentUri: documentPath,
      source: 'contentUri',
      mimeType: 'text/html',
    },
  };

  const [operation] = await client.createDocument(request);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  console.log(`Document created`);
}
```

When I call that function with the path to the HTML file and the correct knowledge base full name and project ID, I get a `Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Documents of type text/html are not supported for EXTRACTIVE_QA.` error back. Is there any way to fix this, or to figure out what MIME-types are supported?

Also somewhat related, but I also can't seem to create documents using the `rawContent` source type. Changing the request to:

```
const request = {
  parent: knowledgeBaseFullName,
  document: {
    knowledgeTypes: ['EXTRACTIVE_QA'],
    displayName: 'test',
    rawContent: base64Content,
    source: 'rawContent',
    mimeType: 'text/html',
  },
};
```

gives a `Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: None of the source field is defined.` error.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote my comment on the other answer:

> `rawContent` seems to be implemented in the latest version of the npm package (`0.9.1`). @emilianop11 's answer is still correct for version `0.6.0`, however you must use the original content (the `rawContent` passed to the `createDocument` function, not the base64 encoded content (the `base64data` variable).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a really similar problem.
I needed to read through the nodejs library code to figure this out. 
[Here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/blob/ceb520c3f932c4081b41577fc03cde2306631ea1/src/v2beta1/doc/google/cloud/dialogflow/v2beta1/doc_document.js) we can see that `rawContent` is not yet implemented in the library, so we still need to use `content` (which according to the docs will be deprecated). This should do the trick:

```
async createDocument(
  knowledgeBaseFullName,
  rawContent,
  documentName
) {

  // Instantiate a DialogFlow Documents client.
  const client = new dialogflowV2.DocumentsClient({
    projectId: this.projectId,
  });

  let buff = new Buffer(rawContent);  
  let base64data = buff.toString('base64');

  const projectId = this.projectId;
  knowledgeBaseFullName = '';
  const knowledgeTypes = 'EXTRACTIVE_QA';
  const mimeType = 'text/plain';

  const request = {
    parent: knowledgeBaseFullName,
    document: {
      knowledgeTypes: [knowledgeTypes],
      displayName: documentName,
      content: base64data,
      source: 'rawContent',
      mimeType: mimeType,
    },
  };

  const [operation] = await client.createDocument(request);
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  }
```

Comment: `rawContent` seems to be implemented in the latest version of the npm package (`0.9.1`). 

@emilianop11 's answer is still correct for version `0.6.0`, however you must use the original content (the `rawContent` passed to the `createDocument` function, **not** the base64 encoded content (the `base64data` variable).